# View digital signature of executable

Tags: certificate, windbg

**Is there a way to view, verify or extract the digital signature information of an executable in WinDbg?**

So far I found out that the executable has a security directory:

```
0:048> !dh customerapp
...
       0 [       0] address [size] of Export Directory
    43DC [      64] address [size] of Import Directory
    7000 [   47C38] address [size] of Resource Directory
    6000 [     1A4] address [size] of Exception Directory
   4C600 [    1ED8] address [size] of Security Directory
...
```

Looking at the memory does not help:

```
0:048> db customerapp+4C600 
00000000`0044c600  ff ff ff 00 ff ff ff 00-ff ff ff 00 ff ff ff 00  ................
00000000`0044c610  ff ff ff 00 ff ff ff 00-ff ff ff 00 ff ff ff 00  ................
00000000`0044c620  ff ff ff 00 ff ff ff 00-ff ff ff 00 ff ff ff 00  ................
00000000`0044c630  ff ff ff 00 ff ff ff 00-ff ff ff 00 ff ff ff 00  ................
...
```

I expected to see at least some strings like `DigiCert` or similar.